# pg gem fails to install on omnibus Chef installation

Tags: postgresql-9.1, chef-infra, pg

Ola all the smart people.
I'm facing a problem which I'm trying to solve but failing. I'm trying to install pg gem on the server which has Omnibus Chef installation on ie http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/

Basically the problem has been reported already (http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1406) but I'm looking for a solution to this if there is any - the workaround suggested to install packages from Opscode Ubuntu repos - but those come with ruby 1.8 - I hope I dont have to continue further why I'm feeling reluctant to do that :)

The error I'm getting when installing the pg gem is:

```
$ sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install pg 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Faulting bits in the mkmf.log is as follows:

```
have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -lpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_certificate_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `TLSv1_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -lpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:7:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:243:16: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -llibpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpq
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -llibpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:7:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:243:16: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -lms/libpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lms/libpq
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/opt/chef/embedded/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/chef/embedded/include    -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/chef/embedded/include -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -Wl,-R/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib     -Wl,-R -Wl,/opt/chef/embedded/lib -L/opt/chef/embedded/lib -lruby -lms/libpq  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:7:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘PQconnectdb’
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h:243:16: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I think the problem is that pg gem is linked against a different lib than the one postgresql was built against and the compile fails. I'm just wondering if there is anything I could do to work around this ?
Any amazing bright minds ? 
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the pg gem to install by downloading the postgresql source, and compiling it by building vs the libraries in /opt/chef/embedded. This is not optimal, but it should work (caveat: I haven't tried it in a recipe or a ruby program):

```
apt-get install -y build-essential
apt-get build-dep -y postgresql
wget http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.2.1/postgresql-9.2.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf postgresql-9.2.1.tar.gz
cd postgresql-9.2.1
export MAJOR_VER=9.2
./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/chef/embedded \
  --mandir=/opt/chef/embedded/share/postgresql/${MAJOR_VER}/man \
  --docdir=/opt/chef/embedded/share/doc/postgresql-doc-${MAJOR_VER} \
  --sysconfdir=/etc/postgresql-common \
  --datarootdir=/opt/chef/embedded/share/ \
  --datadir=/opt/chef/embedded/share/postgresql/${MAJOR_VER} \
  --bindir=/opt/chef/embedded/lib/postgresql/${MAJOR_VER}/bin \
  --libdir=/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ \
  --libexecdir=/opt/chef/embedded/lib/postgresql/ \
  --includedir=/opt/chef/embedded/include/postgresql/ \
  --enable-nls \
  --enable-integer-datetimes \
  --enable-thread-safety \
  --enable-debug \
  --with-gnu-ld \
  --with-pgport=5432 \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-libedit-preferred \
  --with-includes=/opt/chef/embedded/include \
  --with-libs=/opt/chef/embedded/lib
make
sudo make install
sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/chef/embedded/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_config
```

https://gist.github.com/3954641

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. But we don't like that for 2 reasons:
1.) every Postgres upgrade means recompile
2.) getting this working in postgres cookbook would require a lot of changes and generally messes things up.

Nevertheless thanks for your answer

Comment: Yeah, it's totally sub-optimal. It's only an issue if you want to use the pg gem in Chef though, such as in Opscode's database cookbook resources for postgresql database and user management. If you're using pg only in your app, this isn't required, just install the gem under the Ruby your app uses (we don't recommend the Ruby in the omnibus package).

Comment: That is, we don't recommend Chef's ruby for your app, only for Chef :-).

Comment: yeah thats right - it's an issue if you want to use pg gem in Chef. It's not only about user management - it's pretty much any Postgres management done via Chef which is affected in my opinion. Having a bunch of execute resources feels almost like coming back to old times when the Infra was driven by bunch of shell scripts. It's a shame that no one has addressed this though yet, so we have to work around this.

Comment: @jtimberman: So is this the recommended way to be able to use the `database` cookbook?  I'm getting this error after this line in my recipe: `include_recipe 'database::postgresql'`,  Yet the `apt-get build-dep -y postgresql` doesn't seem to work for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Nevermind... re-running test-kitchen seems to have fixed it after throwing this warning:  `WARN: Failed to properly build pg gem. Forcing properly linking and retrying (omnibus fix)`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "-lssl -lcrypto" while compiling.
It worked for me when compiling openssl based applications